# Attach unique properties to LineGeometry objects in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

We know that there is Tag property for Shape objects that comes very handy when attaching properties to the shapes drawn on the canvas. On the other hand we are encouraged that we should use lightweight drawing objects for example: `LineGeometry`

How can I attach unique properties to instances of this class?

Note:
I want to add like 1000+ lines to the canvas, I also want to be able to recognize which is which. Since these lines will represent various parts of structural elements like rebars. So I want to be able to click on a line and recognize which rebar it represents.

Comment: you *could* create [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx), however, it is likely that you're taking a wrong approach to begin with. Depending on the nature of the Data you're dealing with, or *what* data you want to associate, the UI might not be the right place for that data. Please post some additional information about the properties you're trying to add to these UI elements, to get a better answer.

Comment: @HighCore I'm guessing that I'm on the wrong path too. I added some notes. I'd really appreciate any help that puts me in the right direction.

Comment: @HighCore After 3 weeks, now I know what you meant! I have the habit of coming back and reading my old posts! I learn a lot! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LineGeometry` was declared as [`sealed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx) which means that you cannot extend it directly. However, there is nothing stopping you from declaring a new class with a property of type `LineGeometry` and your new property in it:

```
public class ExtendedLineGeometry
{
    public object CustomProperty { get; set; }
    public LineGeometry LineGeometry { get; set; }
}
```

Then, wherever you want to access the `LineGeometry` object, you would just need to reference it like this:

```
Path myPath = new Path();
myPath.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
myPath.StrokeThickness = 1;
myPath.Data = extendedLineGeometry.LineGeometry;
```

Depending on what you put in your extra property, you could define it as a `double`, maybe even add another one and do something like this:

```
Path myPath = new Path();
myPath.Stroke = extendedLineGeometry.CustomProperty;
myPath.StrokeThickness = extendedLineGeometry.CustomProperty2;
myPath.Data = extendedLineGeometry.LineGeometry;
```

---

UPDATE >>>

I thought that I just explained how you would use it. However, your comment leads me to believe that you didn't understand. Your `GeometryGroup.Children` property can take a `LineGeometry` object. Your `ExtendedLineGeometry` object has a `LineGeometry` object in it, so all you need to do is to pass it to the `Children` collection:

```
geometryGroup.Children.Add(extendedLineGeometry.LineGeometry);
```

Comment: Actually I have tried this but then how could I add these to GeometryGroup class. It doesn't accept this extended class.